# Creating a recording in Swift

Tags: swift, audio, avfoundation, avaudiorecorder, recording

I'm beginning to teach myself Swift by creating an app that lets users record voice memos. Many of the previous questions on this topic seem to use an outdated version of Swift, so I thought I'd ask the community for their help.

The problem seems to lie either in my playAudio() function or in my viewDidLoad() function where I set up the recording URL (or both). Please let me know if I can provide additional information.

```
@IBAction func playAudio(sender: AnyObject) throws {

    if audioRecorder?.recording == false {

        stopButton.enabled = true
        recordButton.enabled = false
            let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("audioFile", ofType: "m4a")
            let fileURL = try NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileURL, fileTypeHint: nil)
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer.delegate = self
            print("here you go!")
    }
}
```

override func viewDidLoad() {

```
    super.viewDidLoad()

    playButton.enabled = false
    stopButton.enabled = false

    do {
        let dirPaths =
            NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)

        let baseURL = NSURL(string: dirPaths[0])
        let soundFileURL = NSURL(string:"sound.caf", relativeToURL: baseURL)
        let absoluteURL = soundFileURL!.absoluteURL
        let recordSettings = [AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.Min.rawValue, AVEncoderBitRateKey: 16, AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2, AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0]
        var error: NSError?

        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, withOptions: [])

        if let err = error {
            print("audioSession error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
        }

        try audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: absoluteURL, settings: recordSettings as! [NSObject : AnyObject] as! [String: AnyObject])
        print(audioRecorder!.url)
        if let err = error {
            print("audioSession error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            audioRecorder?.prepareToRecord()
        }

    } catch {
        print("catching error!")
    }
```

Comment: What error do you get? I'm guessing file not found, is that true?

Comment: This is what I see: ///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/389A4125-0C7C-4AF9-8B5C-225B6A3425A7/sound.caf
2015-11-17 23:31:56.854 AppName[7076:3307927] -[AppName.ViewController playAudio:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15564e430
2015-11-17 23:31:56.859 AppName[7076:3307927] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppName.ViewController playAudio:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15564e430'
*** First throw call stack:
...
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. It seems like you're adding a target but you don't define the function. check for that in your code. that's the only thing I can think of

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29461076/error-when-trying-to-play-audio-in-iphone-app

Comment: Peyman, thanks for all of your help. Unfortunately, the link you sent didn't apply to my situation, since I have defined all of the functions that I call.

Comment: szeret, I'm really confused why this isn't working for you. If you want, you can put your code on github, I'll play with it tonight. It's an interesting problem for me.

Comment: Peyman, I appreciate your offer. I spent an hour yesterday trying to publish the repository on github, but I kept getting error messages. I'll let you know if I'm successful trying tomorrow. Otherwise, I'll just start over with new code.